# How to convert a Arraylist of CharSequence to an ArrayList of String

Tags: android, arraylist

I pass my arraylist of strings from one activity to another using intents but I am able to only recover it by getCharSequenceArrayList. I am able to convert ArrayList of CharSequence to ArrayList String as below.

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> arrayList = getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArrayList("employeesList");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();++i)
        {
            arrayList1.add(arrayList.get(i).toString());
        }
```

I was wondering if there was any concise way to convert the whole arraylist of charSequence to ArrayList Of String in one single step

Comment: This is probably the most concise way, given that Android Java does not support streams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following code does exactly what you asked for

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> arrayList = getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArrayList("employeesList");

//This line copies all elements of ArrayList to arrayList1
ArrayList arayList1 = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);
```